# Fullscreen LazyHStack for Images (Landscape)

Tags: swift, swiftui, scrollview, hstack

This is my first question ever on StackOverflow so please bear with me!

How do I get a fullscreen ScrollView with LazyHStack while ignoring safe edges with the each image taking up 100% of the device screen?

I was able to get something like this that worked using TabView but since there is no "LazyTabView" it was not an efficient way to do things.. I have also tried multiple other methods utilizing Geometry Reader and frame but to no avail. Also note that I am strictly working in landscape orientation so how it looks in portrait does not matter to me.

Here is the code I'm currently using:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
            ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                LazyHStack() {
                    Image("test")
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFill()
                    Image("test")
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFill()
                    Image("test")
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFill()
                    Image("test")
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFill()
                }
            }
            .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

I have also attached an image to show the results I am getting. I am hoping I can have the image take up 100% of the screen real estate without showing the edge of the next image. As you can see the image does not fill the entire screen and instead shows the edge of the next photo. I hope this makes sense!

[screenshot of code with preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lg08z.png)

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me:

```
    struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { g in
            ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                HStack() {
                    Image("test")
                        .resizable()
                        .ignoresSafeArea()
                        .frame(width: g.size.width + CGFloat(g.safeAreaInsets.leading) + CGFloat(g.safeAreaInsets.trailing), height: g.size.height + CGFloat(g.safeAreaInsets.bottom))
                        .offset(x: -CGFloat(g.safeAreaInsets.leading))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It will make the image take up the whole screen, ignoring the safe area. You may have to take the code out of the LazyHStack and into a HStack instead, however. Unless you have a large number of images, you do not need to use LazyHStack.